# Nginx Websocket Configuration for Dual Proxies

Tags: nginx, websocket

I am trying to make websocket requests to go through two nginx proxies. It is to do SSR(server side rendering)

My stack is like:
External World <-> nginx <-> rendora(SSR) <-> nginx <-> daphne <-> django

When I was doing
External World <-> nginx <-> daphne <-> django

Websocket connections were established very well. But when I implemented rendora(SSR) and added another proxy to nginx, it does not work. Websocket connection fails while handshakes. I guess "Upgrade" requests fail somewhere in my nginx servers. My nginx conf is like below:

```
server {
        listen 8000;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock;
        }
}

server {
        server_name mydomain;
        charset utf-8;

        location /static {
                alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/apps/web-build/static;
        }
        location /      {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ...
}
```

So the location / port 443 sends all requests from external world to 127.0.0.1:3001 where rendora(SSR server) is listening to. And the SSR server (rendora) forwards them to 127.0.0.1:8000 where nginx proxy to connect to daphne unix socket.

SSR itself works well except the websocket requests.
But I have no idea why websocket upgrade is not done when requests have to go through two nginx proxies.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by making /graphql websocket requests going directly to Daphne server. I still have no idea why websocket connection does not work when I route them to another nginx proxy server.

```
location /graphql {
                        include proxy_params;
                        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                    }

location /      {
          include proxy_params;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
            }
```